# Shuffle JButton position inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, random, jbutton

I've made 9 buttons inside `JPanel` using netbeans IDE 8.2, but I am confused how to make the position of 9 buttons to be random.

This is my code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package projetu;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class shuffle extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form shuffle
     */
    public shuffle() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 3));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jPanel1.add(jButton2);

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");
        jPanel1.add(jButton3);

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");
        jPanel1.add(jButton4);

        jButton5.setText("jButton5");
        jPanel1.add(jButton5);

        jButton6.setText("jButton6");
        jPanel1.add(jButton6);

        jButton7.setText("jButton7");
        jPanel1.add(jButton7);

        jButton8.setText("jButton8");
        jPanel1.add(jButton8);

        jButton9.setText("jButton9");
        jPanel1.add(jButton9);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shuffle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shuffle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shuffle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shuffle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new shuffle().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: changing the text of the buttons instead of its positions in layout will be 100 times better.... can be that a solution?

Comment: Add them to some kind of `List`, use `Collections.shuffle` to randomise the `List` and then add the buttons

Answer (score 1):

JPanel does have an overloaded add method that takes a Component and an int: add(Component,int). By using Math.random(), multiplying it, then converting it to an integer, you can use that overload to randomize the position to insert the component. For jButton1, it can stay the way it is. Starting with jButton2, code:

```
jpanel1.add(jButton2, (int)(Math.random() * 2));
```

This will insert jButton2 at either before or after jButton1. For jButton3, code:

```
jpanel1.add(jButton3, (int)(Math.random() * 3));
```

And so forth. Make sure that all (Math.random() * int) are in parentheses after (int) or it will not evaluate correctly.